# set a variable based on the value of an environment variable

Tags: make

Inside my makefile, I need to set a variable based on an environment variable called `MY_SERVER_ENV`.

I tried this:

```
gulp:=./node_modules/.bin/gulp
ifeq ($(MY_SERVER_ENV), 'prod')
    branch:=production
else
    branch:=deploy
endif


checkvariable:
    @echo $$branch
```

The output I get :

> $ MY_SERVER_ENV=prod make checkvariable
>
> $

The idea is to set the variable `branch` to `production` if the environment variable `MY_SERVER_ENV` equals `prod`, else to set `branch` to `deploy`.

And as you can see `echo $$branch` displays nothing

Comment: It says the error is at `exit(1)`. It's not related to your variable.

Comment: `exit(1)` is juste to stop the script, but as you can see the echo branch displays nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`branch` should be accessed as `$(branch)`, and using

```
ifeq ($(MY_SERVER_ENV), 'prod')
```

will compare the value of `$MY_SERVER_ENV` with the literal string `'prod'` (including the single quotes).

```
gulp:=./node_modules/.bin/gulp

ifeq "$(MY_SERVER_ENV)" "prod"
    branch:=production
else
    branch:=deploy
endif

help:
        @echo $(branch)
```

The `ifeq` can be on the following forms:

```
ifeq (arg1, arg2)
ifeq 'arg1' 'arg2'
ifeq "arg1" "arg2"
ifeq "arg1" 'arg2'
ifeq 'arg1' "arg2"
```

Reference: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_7.html

Comment: Cool that's it :), any references please?

Comment: @smarber I changed it slightly after looking up the correct syntax.

Comment: `ifeq ("$(PROJECT_ENV)", "prod")` this works for me

Comment: @smarber Good, but I think the quotes will be part of the strings compared. Since it's the same quoting on both sides, this does not matter.